# Find Focus To Know What To Copy

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus, copy-paste

I have a Copy button in my Ribbon and I need to determine what control is focused so I know which Copy method to invoke. Any ideas on how to do this? I was thinking FocusManager.GetFocusedElement but I am using MVVM so I don't know what to pass as an argument.

```
private void Copy()
    {
        if (**Here_I_need_to_know_what_is_focused** is DataGridCell)
        {
            ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, this.DisplayedData);
        }
        else if ((this.CurrentFiles.SelectedItem is DSViewModel) || (this.CurrentFiles.SelectedItem is QViewModel))
        {
            this.CurrentFiles.Copy(this.CurrentFiles.SelectedItem);
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, Keyboard.FocusedElement);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not MVVM.  You should be exposing an ICommand and passing the target of what needs to be copied as the command parameter.

Comment: Yes, I do expose an ICommand which the View binds to. This is the method that is called by the ICommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends where your code is located.

I assume that it is located in the view model - in this case you will not have access to the `FocusMangager` directly. In order to get the currently focused element, you will have to pass it to the function via the `CommandParameter` attribute. This can be done by binding if there is only one possible target object.

However, I can imagine that this might be not an option, as the copy button in your ribbon most likely handles several objects. In this case I would not use the `Command` and `CommandParameter` attributes, but implement a click handler in the code behind.

Here, you now got the option to determine the focussed element or other target object using all the view's functionality, including the `FocusManager`. After you have determined the target you now can call you command's `Execute` method passing the correct object as a parameter.

Before trying to get the focused element you should, however, query the `CanExecute` method so that you only determine the target object if the command can be executed. If you want to enable/disable the copy button based on the outcome of the `CanExecute` method, some additional work is required.

**Note:** [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2410585/266919) suggests that there might be some problems using  the focus manger with the `DataGrid`.